# Force CUDA's thrust::reduce to execute with no parallelism

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a CUDA program that uses thrust::reduce to parallelize sums: for example,

```
thrust::device_ptr<double> tmp(aux);
double my_sum = thrust::reduce(tmp, tmp + G);
```

where `double* aux` points to `G` contiguous doubles on the device. I need to compare the runtime of the whole parallelized program to a version with no parallel computation. Is there a way to run `thrust::reduce` using only a single thread on the device? A global switch would be the most convenient option.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do this by invoking `thrust::reduce` within a kernel using the serial execution policy and then launching that kernel with a single thread. Something like:

```
__global__ void serial_reduce(double *result, double *aux, int G)
{
    *result = thrust::reduce(thrust::seq, aux, aux+G);
}

double *result;
cudaMallocManaged(&result, sizeof(double));
serial_reduce<<<1,1>>>(result, aux, G);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

[Note written in browser and totally untested, use at own risk]